# Position Mesh inside sphere, making textures fit

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I'm trying to position a part of a texture that is being rendered on a portion of a SphereGeometry, inside a full SphereGeometry.

I attach a jsfiddle so you can see what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/ggL3uemh/23/

If you open the link, you will see that the smaller texture in the scene is a part of the bigger one.

The bigger one is rendered on a big full sphere.

The smaller one, is rendered on a portion of a sphere.

I want to give the smaller Mesh the proper position, rotation and scale so it can perfectly fit inside the sphere making it look like the smaller one isn't even there.

I suspect the part of the sphere is not correct either...

```
this.videoCustomGeometry = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(500, 64, 64, 1, 1.8, 1, 0.9);
this.videoCustomGeometry.scale( - 1, 1, 1 );
```

I came close to find the position, using a raycaster and attaching the next code to the mousemove event:

```
this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);
var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects([this.pano], false);
```

And then, I get the exact position where the smaller Mesh should be positioned, but I don't know about the rotation, scale, or if the geometry the smaller Mesh is using is correct.

I'm stuck... thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a suggestion: First, position the texture on the smaller cube such that the center of the cropped area is at `x=0, y=0` (for the camera). Next, calculate where that center exists _on the larger sphere_ (should result in a `Vector3`). Now you can use `Object3D.lookAt(Vector3)` to make the _small sphere_ look at that position. Afterward, you may need to adjust the `up` vector (roll), but the cropped texture should be in the correct position, spatially.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know if it is a lot to ask for, but, could you fork the jsfiddle and try to show me how you would do that? I try to understand you but a few questions come up to my mind and I think it would be way easier if I could see some code. Thanks a lot Jim